# Flutter project import Android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

So im new to flutter and wanted to check out an example project to see how its set up architecure wise. For this i stumbled upon InKino. Looks like a nice app to check out as example.

https://github.com/roughike/inKino

When i open Android Studio > file > Open... and select the folder that i have cloned previously it somehow does not detect that its a flutter project. And cant seem to run it

[image]

However when creating a new flutter project everything is working fine and i can run my project as per usual.

I have installed latest flutter and dart plugins for Android Studio. Also the flutter SDK and Dart sdk are installed.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the repository you linked and my Android Studio identified the project as flutter project. What I did is opening the `mobile` sub folder not the whole repository folder, because the repository contains multiple different type of projects.